# When using INNER JOIN , Is there any way where I can concat multiple rows data from table 2 into one row of data (comma separated values )

Tags: php, mysql

Currently , When I use joins then each row from cust_base has 3 rows of data .(due to 3 values from cust_addition_value table ).
I want multiple rows of data into one single row with comma separated values .

Here is the code :

```
 $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 
  cust_base.field1,cust_base.field2,cust_addition_value.field3
  FROM cust_base INNER JOIN cust_addition_value on cust_base.id=cust_addition_value.cid");
 $statement->execute();
 $data1 =$statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Please decide which database youre using, and state the version also

Comment: Php version 7.0 mysql 8.0.25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT 
  cust_base.field1,cust_base.field2,GROUP_CONCAT(cust_addition_value.field3)
  FROM cust_base INNER JOIN cust_addition_value on cust_base.id=cust_addition_value.cid
  GROUP BY cust_base.field1,cust_base.field2
```